# Sorting an ArrayList<Node> lexicographically?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist

i want to sort an ArrayList that has the type Node, like this :

```
 [[country1: null], [name2: null], [city3: null], [region4: null], [name6: null]]
```

To get the value of Node's name i use the function getNodeName() so

```
 ArrayNode.get(0).getNodeName()  // return country1
```

I have looking into  **collection.sort** but i don't know how i will do it, Thank u in advance.

Comment: How does the `Node` class look? By what of it's properties to you want to sort?

Comment: Not an *exact* duplicate, but pretty much of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) object to define comparison logic.

Something like that:

```
ArrayList<Node> nodes;
        Collections.sort(nodes, new Comparator<Node>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Node o1, Node o2) {
                return o1.getNodeName().compareTo(o2.getNodeName());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want java.util.Comparator. You can use that with Collections.sort

Answer (score 3):

Create a `Comparator` that sorts by node name, then `Collections.sort(list,comparator)`